# Setting Yaxis in Matplotlib using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using Pandas to plot in IPython Notebook, I have several plots and because Matplotlib decides the Y axis it is setting them differently and we need to compare that data using the same range.

From the Matplotlib doc it seems that I need to set `ylim`, but can't figure the syntax to do so. I have tried several variants on:

```
df2250.plot(); plt.ylim((100000,500000))
df2260.plot()
df5.plot()
```

I assume I'll need to apply the limits to each plot, but since I can't get one working...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Pandas plot() returns the axes, you can use it to set the ylim on it.

```
ax1 = df2250.plot()
ax2 = df2260.plot()
ax3 = df5.plot()

ax1.set_ylim(100000,500000)
ax2.set_ylim(100000,500000)
etc...
```

You can also pass an axes to Pandas plot, so plotting it in the same axes can be done like:

```
ax1 = df2250.plot()
df2260.plot(ax=ax1)
etc...
```

If you want a lot of different plots, defining the axes beforehand and within one figure might be the solution that gives you the most control:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(10,4), subplot_kw={'ylim': (100000,500000)})

df2260.plot(ax=axs[0])
df2260.plot(ax=axs[1])
etc...
```

Comment: You could also add `sharey=True` to `plt.subplots`.  Then the y-limits will stay the same even when you zoom in on a particular subplot.

Answer (score 94):

[DataFrame.plot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) exposes a `ylim` parameter that sets the y axis limits:

```
df.plot(ylim=(0, 200))
```

I'm guessing this feature was added after [Rutger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17787498/4518341) was accepted in 2013.