# How to plot values from the DataFrame? Python 3.0

Tags: dataframe, pythonplotter

I'm trying to plot the values from the A column against the index(Of the DataFrame table), but it doesnt allow me to. How to do it?

**INDEX** is the index from the DataFrame and not the declared variable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need plot column `A` only, index is used for `x` and values for `y` by default in [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
#line is default method, so omitted
Test['A'].plot(style='o')
```

Another solution is [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for column from `index` and then [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
Test.reset_index().plot(x='index', y='A', style='o')
```

Sample:

```
Test=pd.DataFrame({'A':[3.0,4,5,10], 'B':[3.0,4,5,9]})
print (Test)
      A    B
0   3.0  3.0
1   4.0  4.0
2   5.0  5.0
3  10.0  9.0

Test['A'].plot(style='o')
```

[image: graph]

---

```
print (Test.reset_index())
   index     A    B
0      0   3.0  3.0
1      1   4.0  4.0
2      2   5.0  5.0
3      3  10.0  9.0

Test.reset_index().plot(x='index', y='A', style='o')
```

[image: graph1]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If I want the y-axis to run from 0 to 10, how can I do it?

Comment: You need `ax = Test['A'].plot(style='o')`
`ax.set_ylim(0,10)` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787366/setting-yaxis-in-matplotlib-using-pandas)